# How long does Singapore Frequent Traveller status last?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, singapore

Singapore allows visitors of certain nationalities to enroll in the [Frequent Traveller Programme](https://www.ica.gov.sg/enteringanddeparting/visitor/ftp), entitling them to use automated immigration, like Singapore citizens and residents.

However, it's unclear to me how long this status lasts. Is it permanent? Or does it expire after a fixed period, or when your passport expires?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked the Singapore ICA (Immigration & Checkpoints Authority) and received this reply:

> Applicants who intend to apply for Frequent Traveller will be granted with a maximum of 5 years duration or minus 6 months from the passport expiry date duration depending on their passport expiry date.
>
> The Frequent Traveller can be renewable if there is a change in passport or the Frequent Traveller status expires.
>
> For the first time application of Frequent Traveller as well as the renewal process, the applicants need to visit to our eIACS enrolment centre.